# Go Quiz exercise, part of Gophercises

Tags: csv, go

This is the first exercise from https://gophercises.com/.

Basically the idea is to parse a CSV file in a form of 'question:answer' and count the number of correct answers. Also you have a time out range in which you must finish it.

I would appreciate any comments, good or bad :) Thanks a lot !

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/csv"
        "os"
        "fmt"
        "flag"
        "time"
)

const Ready = "yes"

var correctAnswers int

func getFileContent(filename string) (records[][] string, err error) {
        fd, err := os.Open(filename)

        if err != nil {
                exit("Problem with opening the file")
        }

        reader := csv.NewReader(fd)
        return reader.ReadAll()
}

func outputResult(totalQuestions, correctAnswers int) {
        fmt.Println("Number of total questions:", totalQuestions)
        fmt.Println("Number of corrected answers:", correctAnswers)
}

func exit(message string) {
        fmt.Println(message)
        os.Exit(3)
}

func provideQuestions(questions[][] string, done chan bool) {
        for index, value := range questions {
                question, answer := value[0], value[1]
                fmt.Println("Question N:=", index+1, "=>", question)

                var userAnswer string
                fmt.Scanf("%s", &userAnswer)

        if userAnswer == answer {
            correctAnswers ++
        }
        }

        done <- true
}


func main() {
    fileName := flag.String("name of csv file", "problems.csv", "The name of the csv file - default to 'problems.csv'")
    allowedTime := flag.Int("allowed time", 10, "The duration in seconds for which the quizz must be finished.")
    flag.Parse()

    var readyToStart string
    fmt.Println("Type 'yes' if you are ready to start")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &readyToStart)

    if readyToStart != Ready {
        fmt.Println("Come back later if you are ready")
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    records, err := getFileContent(*fileName)


    if err != nil {
            exit("Reader problem.")
    }
    

    done := make(chan bool)
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(*allowedTime) * time.Second)
    
    go provideQuestions(records, done)

    select {
    case <- done:
            fmt.Println("Great job")
            fmt.Println("You finished with all questions.")
    case <- timer.C:
            fmt.Println("Time expired")
        }

    outputResult(len(records), correctAnswers)

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function returns `error`, but actually you don't return it and exit in the function body when opening the file:

```
func getFileContent(filename string) (records[][] string, err error) {
        fd, err := os.Open(filename)

        if err != nil {
                exit("Problem with opening the file")
        }

        reader := csv.NewReader(fd)
        return reader.ReadAll()
}
```

From the point of error handling it will be more consistent to return error:

```
fd, err := os.Open(filename)
if err != nil {
   return nil, err
}
```

The file was open, but not closed: `defer fd.Close()`.

I don't remember `flag` package, but if it is not ensure the presence of parameter you need to check `filename != nil`:

```
records, err := getFileContent(*fileName)
```

Here you have created new goroutine, but returns the result via global variable `correctAnswers`:

```
done := make(chan bool)
go provideQuestions(records, done)
```

It stops working if you decide to improve your game and allow more than one person to play on the same time. You will have **race condition** on this variable. Much better return the value from goroutine using channel.

You already have such channel - `done`, just change its type to channel of `int` and return the number of correct answers using it.

Answer (score 1):

### Improving the quiz

**Parsing user input**

You should parse all user input, including the csv file, by stripping them from white-spaces and making it lower-case. This ensures that user supplied data is correctly handled and the user doesn't fail a Question while it should be correct.

Let's take for example the following quiz in the csv:

*What is the capital of the UK, london*

The user might have it correct but it could be stated as incorrect in the following ways:

1. You don't Trim the csv, and it's easy to forget a white-space in there
2. A user could answer with London (Capital L)

Secondly there could be a *malformed* csv file, with only 1 item in the line, this would break the code without giving any indication why to the user.

**Randomise**

It would be nice if the problems were shuffled to avoid repetition.